# Form And Code Unsynched

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox with some text in it ("hello"). If I change the text to anything else and get the text from the textbox (through the code), I'll get "hello" although I changed it.

In another case, when I change a checkbox's check state, the checkbox won't visually tick (or untick).

Anyone has an idea what's going on and how to sync them?

I've opened a new project,
thats the only function on my form :

```
public void Switch()
    {
        Checkbox1.Checked = !Checkbox1.Checked;
    }
```

and I call it from the program.cs :

```
static MainForm MyForm;
MyForm = new MainForm();
MyForm.Switch();
```

Comment: Are you doing it from the UI thread? Also, can we see some code?

Comment: You are using the wrong form object reference.

Comment: I've edited the post with what might be the problem

Comment: Could you post your entire project?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are simply instantiating `MainForm` in `Main` and then calling `Switch`.

Which means that you are not sending the request on the UI Thread.

So, you can [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) your code to run on the UI thread:

```
public void Switch()
{
    // true if off of the UI thread, and thus must be Invoked
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // off UI thread; put it onto it
        this.Invoke(Switch);
    }
    else
    {
        // on UI thread
        Checkbox1.Checked = ! Checkbox1.Checked;
    }
}
```

You should only interact with the UI from the UI Thread. You should not litter your code with `Invoke`s unless you expect to call it off of the UI Thread, or you provide a means for others to do so (some public API).